# Why does Boost.Concept call destructors through null pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, clang-static-analyzer, c++-concepts

When analyzing some Boost dependent code through the Clang static analyzer, I got the following error:

> Logic error   Called C++ object pointer is null   usage.hpp   22

from the following code in `boost/concept/usage.hpp`

```
template <class Model>
struct usage_requirements
{
    ~usage_requirements() { ((Model*)0)->~Model(); }
};
```

**Question**: is this a real bug in Boost or does Boost.Concept call a destructor through a null pointer to somehow generate compiler errors during concept checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer. Take this with some salt, I am in no way a Boost Concept expert.

It used in order to make the compiler to instantiate the "Model" destructor to make the compiler generate errors for concept failures.

`usage_requirements` is used together with `BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE` which is used while creating new concepts, see [Creating Concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/concept_check/creating_concepts.htm) in the documentation.

```
#   define BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(model)                                    \
      model(); /* at least 2.96 and 3.4.3 both need this :( */           \
      BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::concepts::usage_requirements<model>)); \
      ~model()
```

Which is used like:

```
BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(InputIterator)
{
    X j(i);             // require copy construction
    same_type(*i++,v);  // require postincrement-dereference returning value_type
    X& x = ++j;         // require preincrement returning X&
}
```

Which will end up like:

```
model(); /* at least 2.96 and 3.4.3 both need this :( */           \
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::concepts::usage_requirements<model>)); \
~model()
{
    X j(i);             // require copy construction
    same_type(*i++,v);  // require postincrement-dereference returning value_type
    X& x = ++j;         // require preincrement returning X&
}
```

As you can see, the concept requirements end up in the `model` destructor. Which is why we need to fool the compiler to instantiate it.

Comment: but wouldn't that also be instantiated through e.g. a temporary `Model().~Model();`?

Comment: @TemplateRex that requires default-constructability. It would be bad to have a concepts library that requires random concepts everywhere. `((Model*)0)`, however, introduces no extra requirements. In C++11 one would use `std::declval<Model>()` instead, which is way less weird and serves the same purpose.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think `static_assert` would be even better with C++11.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ah yes, `declval` is much nicer, and would shut up the static analyzer.